# Remove items from S3 objects array in php

Tags: php, arrays, amazon-s3

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Accounts.csv
    [1] => Book1.xlsx
    [2] => Documents/
    [3] => Documents/AdbWinApi.dll
    [4] => Documents/AdbWinUsbApi.dll
    [5] => Documents/adb.exe
    [6] => Documents/boot.img
    [7] => Documents/fastboot.exe
    [8] => Documents/side_banner.jpg
    [9] => Documents/source.properties
    [10] => File Organization.docx
    [11] => How to Manage Risks.docx
    [12] => How to Trade Forex.docx
    [13] => Ken Doc - Galad Letter Head.pdf
    [14] => Ken Header.png
    [15] => MX_2004_fwmx_2004_en.exe
    [16] => xx.docx
    [17] => asmack-master.zip
    [18] => ca5rmhx7l4-Human Heart 2.7z
    [19] => evasi0n7.exe
    [20] => ken header.pdf
    [21] => sp42471.exe
)
```

and I would like it to return an array like below;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Accounts.csv
    [1] => Book1.xlsx
    [2] => Documents
    [3] => File Organization.docx
    [4] => How to Manage Risks.docx
    [5] => How to Trade Forex.docx
    [6] => Ken Doc - Galad Letter Head.pdf
    [7] => Ken Header.png
    [8] => MX_2004_fwmx_2004_en.exe
    [9] => xx.docx
    [10] => asmack-master.zip
    [11] => ca5rmhx7l4-Human Heart 2.7z
    [12] => evasi0n7.exe
    [13] => ken header.pdf
    [14] => sp42471.exe
)
```

I am using the code below;

{

```
private function listFiles($bucket = null , $prefix = null) {
$ls = S3::getBucket($bucket, $prefix);
if(!empty($ls))  {

foreach($ls as $l) {

$fname = str_replace($prefix,"",$l['name']);

   if(!empty($fname)) { 
     $rv[] = $fname; 
   }
  } 
}
   if(!empty($rv)) { 
     return $rv; 
  }
}
```

}

What changes can I make to my code to get the above results. I am using Donovan Schönknecht Amazon S3 library for codeigniter.

Comment: I'm not certain but are you looking for [unset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) ? eg: `unset($array[$key])`

Comment: @Cybermatatu: Please clearly state what is the difference between Array1 and Array2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `foreach`

```
$newarr=array();
foreach($entries as $v)
{
    if(strpos($v,'/')!==false)
    {
    $v=explode('/',$v);
        if(isset($v[1]) && strlen($v[1])>0){}else{$newarr[]=$v[0];}
    }
    else { $newarr[]=$v;}

}
print_r($newarr);
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/131791)

Comment: What if I am using a multi-dimension array? Like this question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905599/remove-duplicate-items-from-s3-objects-multi-dimension-array-in-php).

Comment: @Cybermatatu, I have added the answer for that question.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the elements with  `$array[3] = "";` e.g. Then u have empty array-elements and then you could use a function like this:

```
    function empty_array($array){
    foreach($array as $ar => $value) {
    if($value == '') {
    unset($array[$ar]);
    }
    }
    return $array;
    } 

    $new_array = emtpy_array($old_array);
```